# Spring MVC and MogoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am getting a strange error in my spring mvc project with MongoDB.
I have this model :

```
@Document(collection = "equipements")
public class EquipementModel {

@Id
private String id;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a name")
@Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "The name size must be between 2 and 10 characters")
public String name;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the OS/iOs ofthe equipement")
public String os;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the version of the equipement")
@Size(min = 2, message = "The version size must contains atleast 2 characters")
public String version;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please select atleast one function")
public ArrayList<String> functions;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please select the category of the equipement")
public String category;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the private IP")
public String privateIp;

public String publicIp;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please specify the hardware")
public String hardware;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please specify the hardware type")
public String hardwareType;

@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide the authentication method")
public String authMethod;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date addedDate;

public List<InterventionsModel> interventions;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getOs() {
    return os;
}

public void setOs(String os) {
    this.os = os;
}

public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getHardware() {
    return hardware;
}

public void setHardware(String hardware) {
    this.hardware = hardware;
}

public String getHardwareType() {
    return hardwareType;
}

public void setHardwareType(String hardwareType) {
    this.hardwareType = hardwareType;
}

public String getAuthMethod() {
    return authMethod;
}

public void setAuthMethod(String authMethod) {
    this.authMethod = authMethod;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Date getAddedDate() {
    return addedDate;
}

public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
    this.addedDate = addedDate;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFunctions() {
    return functions;
}

public void setFunctions(ArrayList<String> functions) {
    this.functions = functions;
}

public String getPrivateIp() {
    return privateIp;
}

public void setPrivateIp(String privateIp) {
    this.privateIp = privateIp;
}

public String getPublicIp() {
    return publicIp;
}

public void setPublicIp(String publicIp) {
    this.publicIp = publicIp;
}

public List<InterventionsModel> getInterventions() {
    return interventions;
}

public void setInterventions(ArrayList<InterventionsModel> interventions) {
    this.interventions = interventions;
}

public EquipementModel() {

    }

}
```

And this model :

```
public class InterventionsModel{

@NotNull
public String title;

@NotNull
public String doneBy;

@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date doneAt;

@NotNull
public TextArea desc;



public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}



public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}



public String getDoneBy() {
    return doneBy;
}



public void setDoneBy(String doneBy) {
    this.doneBy = doneBy;
}



public Date getDoneAt() {
    return doneAt;
}



public void setDoneAt(Date doneAt) {
    this.doneAt = doneAt;
}



public TextArea getDesc() {
    return desc;
}



public void setDesc(TextArea desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}


public InterventionsModel(){

}
```

Each time I restart the server the server, when I try to access to the webapp I get this error :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)

root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:209)
    java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:285)
    sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getPermission(FileURLConnection.java:225)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getPermission(JarFileFactory.java:156)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getCachedJarFile(JarFileFactory.java:126)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:81)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
    java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1041)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1372)
    java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2109)
    org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:101)
    org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:87)
    org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:65)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:109)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:92)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:75)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:91)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:39)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:299)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:489)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:446)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:689)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:314)
```

This error appears at the first page only which is supposed to list all equipements, here is the query :

```
@Repository
public class EquipementService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public List<EquipementModel> listEquipement() {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name"));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, EquipementModel.class);
    }
```

But I noticed that if I take off the interventions field from Equipement Model, everything works fine....

Maybe I am missing some annotation?

Thank you for help guys, I am really blocked for some days now.

Comment: Is this the complete version of `EquipementModel `? If it's not, add the missing parts

Comment: I added the missing part of EquipementModel

Comment: Complete the code of InterventionsModel also

Comment: The InterventionsModel is now complete, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest cause is careless use of  the stack trace. **The code is being recursively called**. ***we have a circular dependency between these two classes.***  you have detected these lines.

OR Depending on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) installed, the default thread stack size may equal to either 512KB, or 1MB. You can increase the thread stack size using the -Xss flag.The format of the -Xss argument is:

```
-Xss<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]
```

Comment: That is what I tought as well, but I already changed the JVM parameters and still the same thing

Comment: Are you calling EquipementModel  in InterventionsModel?

Comment: No, I am not, I'am calling InterventionsModel in EquipementModel